# Read a generic yaml file

Tags: go, yaml

I have a config file in YAML. I want to define a struct which is generic enough for this file.

Example:

```
A:
  B:
  C:
D:
  E:
  F:
  G:
```

Since there is no predefined structure, I am not able to find out a proper struct for this kind of a struct.

PS: struct incorporating all the fields is not acceptable.

Comment: If you want a struct, you need to define the fields, if you don't want to define the fields, you need a map. You can't really have it both ways.

Comment: I thought may be there is a generic way of defining struct for such a case.

Answer (score 0):

Since my config file was a map structure only. So what I did was adding anotheer nested level to the map and create a map of maps. Something like this:

```
    var m := make(map[string](map[string]string))
```

And my config looks like this now:

```
    A:
     B:
      C:
      D:
     E:
      F:
      G:
```